# Trying to store Metadata in GeoPDF

Tags: python, gdal, metadata, geopdf, gdalinfo

Isn't it possible to store Metadata directly in GeoPDF files using GDAL command line tools (gdal_translate, gdal_edit) or GDAL Python?

Something like: gdal_edit -mo "CUTLINE=POLYGON(...)" orig.pdf

Unfortunately, all I can achieve is the creation of an additional *.aux.xml file that includes the Metadata entry (GDAL 2.2.2 Windows 64bit).

Using PyPDF2 to store the Metadata didn't help either, because gdalinfo couldn't read the data.

Do I miss something here?

Comment: Looks like it depends on the Metadata variable: gdal_edit -mo "PRODUCER=POLYGON((...))" orig.pdf ... works

Comment: Ok, not the best idea to use "PRODUCER" for storing custom data. Maybe someone could explain how to use "xml:XMP" for storing custom Metadata?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. Also, here is a great resource [Geospatial PDF](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_pdf.html)

These are two examples of creating metadata as provided in the resource:

**Examples**

*Create a PDF from 2 rasters (main_raster and another_raster), such that main_raster is initially displayed, and they are exclusively displayed :*

```
gdal_translate -of PDF main_raster.tif my.pdf -co LAYER_NAME=main_raster
           -co EXTRA_RASTERS=another_raster.tif -co 
EXTRA_RASTERS_LAYER_NAME=another_raster
           -co OFF_LAYERS=another_raster -co 
EXCLUSIVE_LAYERS=main_raster,another_raster
```

*Create of PDF with some JavaScript :*

```
gdal_translate -of PDF my.tif my.pdf -co JAVASCRIPT_FILE=script.js
where script.js is :
button = app.alert({cMsg: 'This file was generated by GDAL. Do you want to 
visit its website ?', cTitle: 'Question', nIcon:2, nType:2});
```

Comment: Nope, this was not my Intention. I tried something like: gdal_edit -mo "MYDATA=VALUE" orig.pdf